# How can we store BinaryDocument in springData

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am able to create BinaryDocuemnt in CouchBase dB using couch base java library.

JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.create("document_id", JsonObject.create().put("some", "value"));
System.out.println(bucket.insert(doc));

Can we store JsonDocument using Spring-data repository method ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data offers an abstraction over the `JsonDocument`, storing POJO as JSON, so one could say JsonDocument is supported indirectly. There is no support for `BinaryDocument`, as this is orthogonal to Spring Data's concerns.

However you can transitively access the SDK from the Spring Data Couchbase `CouchbaseRepository` and `CouchbaseOperations`:

```
CouchbaseRepository<String> couchRepo;
// ^ note this is the explicit couchbase interface for repositories

Bucket bucket = couchRepo.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket();
//work directly with the couchbase Bucket SDK from here
```